# Workbox - using a custom handler

Tags: javascript, workbox

I'd like to have an array to configure part of the path (to cache the response when it matches a requested URL) and the expiration (to expire the cache after X seconds) but I can't make the 'handler' to work properly.

This is the array to config the path and expiration:

```
const PATHS_TO_CACHE = [
    { url: 'api/v1/destination', expiration: THIRTY_DAYS },
    { url: 'api/v1/hotel', expiration: THIRTY_MINUTES },
];
```

This is the method to cache that calls `cachePath` to match and `pathHandler` to handle:

```
function cachePaths() {
    workbox.routing.registerRoute(cachePath, pathHandler);
}
```

The match method:

```
function cachePath({ url, event }) {
    const match = PATHS_TO_CACHE.find(function(path) {
        return url.href.includes(path.url);
    });

    return match || false;
}
```

And the handler method:

```
function pathHandler({ url, event, params }) {
    return workbox.strategies.staleWhileRevalidate({
        cacheName: 'url-cache',
        plugins: [
            new workbox.cacheableResponse.Plugin({
                statuses: [0, 200],
            }),
            new workbox.expiration.Plugin({
                maxAgeSeconds: params.expiration,
            }),
        ],
    });
}
```

Well, the `pathHandler` is not working and several tries led me to frustration... throwing errors where I need a `return new Response(something)` (did that with `url` and `event`), incorrect get requests and incorrect object responses.

So, how may I build the `pathHandler` method to cache the response for X seconds and still get the correct response?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are slightly mis-using the API.

`workbox.strategies.staleWhileRevalidate({...}) <- Returns a Route`

Sadly the docs here aren't clear about this: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/reference-docs/latest/workbox.strategies

What you want to do is outlined here: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/modules/workbox-strategies#advanced_usage

```
function pathHandler({ url, event, params }) {
    const staleWhileRevalidate = new workbox.strategies.StaleWhileRevalidate({
        plugins:[...],
    });
    return staleWhileRevalidate.handle({event});
})
```

Comment: Sweet, thanks! I'll try it later. I've solved it in another way, but this is still the best option.